# TypeScript disable errors

Tags: typescript, types, tsconfig

I have certain errors in my typescript folder

Example: ts(2300)

Is there a way to disable certain errors by code in my tsconfig.json?

My current tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "problems",
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": ["esnext", "DOM"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "checkJs": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["problems", "playground"]
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have defined `Hash` twice. I am not aware of a rule to stop this from being an error.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the errors you are seeing, it's probably better to try and fix them than disabling typescript. E.g. ts(2300) could be related to the folders included/excluded and might be fixed by setting `skipLibCheck:true` in tsconfig.json

Comment: `skipLibCheck:true`, not working

Comment: I know I defined `Hash` twice, just that I want to treat every file individually or a declaration in another file not affecting my the current file.